# Prove convergence of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue integrable and assume that $f(t)\to 1$ as $t\to \infty$. Prove that for each positive integer $n$ we may define
\begin{equation}
a_n = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty e^{-t/n} f(t)dt \in \mathbb R
\end{equation}
and prove that $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

**my attempt**

Since $0 < \frac{1}{n}e^{-t/n} \leq 1$ on $[0, \infty)$, the existence of each $a_n$ follows from the fact that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (and hence absolutely integrable).
\begin{align}
&|a_n - 1| \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty e^{-t/n} |f(t) - 1| dt \leq \frac{1}{n}\epsilon \int_a^\infty e^{-t/n} dt + \frac{1}{n} \int_0^a e^{-t/n}|f(t) - 1| dt,
\end{align}
where $\epsilon > 0$ and $a$ are chosen such that $|f(t) - 1| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $t \geq a$, which is possible by convergence of $f(t)$ to $1$.
\begin{align}
|a_n - 1| \leq \frac{1}{n}\epsilon \int_a^\infty e^{-t/n} dt + \frac{1}{n} \int_0^a|f(t) - 1| dt \leq \frac{1}{n}\epsilon \int_a^\infty e^{-t/n} dt + \frac{1}{n}M,
\end{align}
where $M$ is some constant.

Then the second term goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

**question 1**

But what is a good way to bound the first term such that it converges to $0$ with $n\to \infty$?

**answer 1**

As Daniel Fischer pointed out in the comments below, one can substitute $u = \frac{t}{n}$ and the first term would integrate to $\epsilon e^{-a/n}$.

Then we have
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n - 1| \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg(\epsilon e^{-a/n} + \frac{1}{n}M\bigg) = \epsilon.
\end{equation}
And since the choice of $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $0 \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty}|a_n - 1| \leq 0$, which implies $a_n \to 1$.

**question 2**

I am curious how $f$ can be Lebesgue integrable on $[0, \infty)$ when it converges to $1$. The measue of the set is infinite but the function does not tend to $0$ and the function is still integrable, could you please give an example? Many thanks.

**answer 2**

As Calvin Khor and Daniel Fischer pointed out in the comment, such an $f$ cannot be Lebesgue integrable. But a way to make sense of the question is that $f$ is integrable on $[0, z]$ for every $z \in (0, \infty)$.

Many thanks to Daniel Fischer and Calvin Khor for their very helpful comments!

Comment: can't L'Hopitale's rule be applied to compute the limit?

Comment: @pointguard0 Could you please elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: what I mean is the fact that both numerator and denominator of $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty e^{-t/n} f(t)dt$ tends to infinity and maybe differentiating both sides (regardless the fact that $n$ is an integer) could be of help.

Comment: Maybe a series expansion of $e^{-t/n}$ would help?

Comment: $f$ can't be Lebesgue integrable (on $[0,\infty)$) with also $f\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$

Comment: With regard to question 2, as Calvin Khor just noted, $f$ can't be Lebesgue-integrable over $[0,\infty)$. What is meant is that $f$ should be Lebesgue-integrable over $[0,z]$ for every $z \in (0,\infty)$, so that all the integrals make sense.

Comment: You can bound the first term using the substitution $u = t/n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Daniel's substitution also gives a proof via dominated convergence, but the dominating function involves making a similar split

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried the substitution and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you think my attempt above to finish the proof is okay? My concern is that as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller, $a$ could potentially be large and thus $M$ could also potentially be large. Thanks!

Comment: You're not quite done yet. Yes, as $\epsilon$ becomes small, unless $f$ is eventually constant (almost everywhere), $a$ will become very large, and $M$ probably too. But that just means one needs to take a large $n$. What you have shows that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\: \lvert a_n - 1\rvert \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \: \biggl(\epsilon e^{-a/n} + \frac{1}{n}M\biggr) = \epsilon\,.$$ And that holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, hence $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \: \lvert a_n - 1\rvert \leqslant 0\,,$$ and that says $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. That's really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

ad **question 1**: First note that there is no loss of generality to assume that $\epsilon<1$ and $a>1$ (why?). Then simply compute the integral in the first term. You should get (unless I made a mistake, which is not unlikely) $\epsilon e^{-a/n}\leq e^{-n}$ (why?), which then goes to zero.

ad **question 2**: Let's assume for starters that $f$ is measurable. Clearly $f$ could not be Lebesgue integrable on the full real line as it is bounded below by $1-\epsilon>0$ in $(a,\infty)$. It is, however, locally integrable  on some interval $[A,\infty)$ (why?). Fortunately, you do not need need the full integrability assumption, you can just assume that $f$ is locally integrable on $[0,\infty)$ (so that you can compute $\int_0^a|f-1|=M<\infty$) and tends to $1$ at $\infty$ and the problem is well posed, as per your solution and my answer for question 1.

Comment: Except possibly for small $n$, we will have $\epsilon e^{-a/n} > e^{-n}$. And in fact $\epsilon e^{-a/n} \to \epsilon$. But that doesn't hurt, we get $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \lvert a_n - 1\rvert \leqslant \epsilon\,.$$ For every $\epsilon > 0$. And thus the desired $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: @Sobolev +1. Thanks a lot for the answer. But as someone already provided similar answers in the comments under the question, I couldn't accept your answer. I'm really sorry and I hope you understand. Thanks again!